# Insert SUMIF formula in vba without defined range

Tags: vba

I have a database sheet (Sheet1) where the datas submitted automatically with userform. everytime a data has been submitted, it will appear on the last row of database. Then I have a column in another sheet (Sheet2) that should show SUMIF formula when the data has been submitted on the Sheet1.

The formula is `=SUM.IF(Sheet1!E..:N..,"TRUE",Sheet1!$E$5:$N$5)`, the problem is The range or row in the formula is not static which means my VBA code has to give the exact row range where a data submitted on the lastrow of Sheet1.

I'm trying to use the formula as a string, But I don't know how to define a dynamic range in my code. The bref code below;

```
Dim LastRow, LastRow2 As Long

LastRow = Sheet1.Range("B2").Value + 6 (I already put counta formula in the column B2)
LastRow2 = Sheet2.Range("B1").Value + 4 (same here)

Sheet2.Range("E" & LastRow2).Formula = "=SUM.IF(Sheet1!E56:N56,""VRAI"",Sheet1!$E$5:$N$5)"
```

(the code where i wanna put my formula, and the problem there is on `E56:N56` because it must be not static)

I tried with -

```
Sheet2.Range("E" & LastRow2).Formula = "=SUM.IF(Sheet1!E"&LastRow&":N"&LastRow&",""VRAI"",Sheet1!$E$5:$N$5)"
```

But it doesn't work.